# Dockerizing - JAVA EAR

Tags: docker

I was assigned to work with ten year old legacy Java project which generates the following artifacts.

```
xxx.jar
xxx.jar
xxx.jar
xxx.war
```

I am asked to dockerize the application and deploy it into Kubernetes. So, I am planning to build the EAR artifact using the below structure

```
lib
   META-INF
   MANIFEST.MF
application.xml
xxx.jar
xxx.jar
xxx.jar
xxx.war
```

My dockerfile would be something like this

```
FROM tibco/bwce:latest
MAINTAINER Tibco
ADD bwce-rest-bookstore-app.ear /EXPOSE 8080

docker build -t bwce-rest-bookstore-app.
```

am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going in the right direction, however few things are wrong with your Dockerfile:

- `MAINTAINER` instruction is [depracted](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#maintainer-deprecated). Use [`LABEL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label) instead.
- [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) instruction require two arguments - source and destination. Assuimg your workdir is `/`:

```
ADD bwce-rest-bookstore-app.ear /
```

- `EXPOSE` instruction must be on it's own line.
- I'm not sure how EAR artifacts work, but you probably need to start your application after container is created. This can be done with `CMD` instruction. For example:

```
CMD ["/apth/to/executable","param1","param2"]
```

Taking all of the above into consideration your Dockerfile should look more or less like this:

```
FROM tibco/bwce:latest
LABEL maintainer="Tibco" #replace MAINTAINER with LABEL
ADD bwce-rest-bookstore-app.ear / #add EAR to root workdir
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/apth/to/executable","param1","param2"]
```

---

I strongly recommend going through [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the EAR artifact and Java, but as per [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add), the `ADD` command can extract `.tar.gz` files but not `.ear` file format, so I think it's better to have a `Dockerfile` like this (see [here](https://everythingwhat.com/how-do-i-unzip-an-ear-file) for extract):

```
FROM tibco/bwce:latest
MAINTAINER Tibco # you can remove this line
ADD bwce-rest-bookstore-app.ear
RUN jar xf bwce-rest-bookstore-app.ear
EXPOSE 8080
```